# Why docker-maven-plugin fails to pick up correct jar file to include in docker image?

Tags: java, maven, docker, maven-docker-plugin

As far as I understand the build flow:

1. `maven-assembly-plugin` builds `/target/my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
2. `maven-jar-plugin` builds `/target/my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` (not sure why we need it)
3. `docker-maven-plugin` suppose to [assemble](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#build-assembly) `artifact-with-dependencies` `/target/my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Nevertheless, for some reason, it picks up the wrong jar artefact.

What am I missing? How to make it work?

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>my-artifact</name>
                <build>
                    <from>java:8-jre</from>
                    <volumes>
                        <volume>/target</volume>
                    </volumes>
                    <entryPoint>
                        <exec>
                            <arg>java</arg>
                            <arg>-jar</arg>
                            <arg>/target/my-artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</arg>
                        </exec>
                    </entryPoint>
                    <assembly>
                        <descriptorRef>artifact-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        <targetDir>/target</targetDir>
                        <mode>dir</mode>
                        <!--<basedir>/target</basedir>-->
                    </assembly>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>docker-build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>docker:start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>docker:stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>Client</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>Client</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

To cite the documentation, :

> ```
>      <descriptorRef>artifact-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
> ```
>
> will add the created artifact with the name
>   ${project.build.finalName}.${artifact.extension} and all jar
>   dependencies in the the targetDir (which is /maven by default).

Which is not what you want.

What you want I think is to customize the assembly to something like this:

```
<assembly>
 <targetDir>/target</targetDir>
 <inline>
    <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target/</directory>
        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
             <include>project-name-version-classifier-jar-with-dependencies.jar</include> 
         </includes>
         </fileSet>
       </fileSets>
     </inline>
   </assembly>
```

Bonus point: Have a look at [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib), it may better suit your needs if your are building an image for a Java project.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I still wonder: I use a custom descriptor, which creates an artifact and it should be attached. But then, docker plugin does not pick that up. Any quick idea why? (I'll probably post a question about that.)

Comment: Have you checked the docs to make sure you're not in a case where the behavior of docker-maven-plugin differs from what you expect? http://dmp.fabric8.io/#build-assembly : section Assembly Descriptor